# Sent Mail / PowerShell Credentials

Tags: powershell, email, credentials

I try to send an email using code based on this example: https://blog.victorsilva.com.uy/credenciales-con-powershell/, but the email is not sending:

```
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$password = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\USUARIOPC\password2.txt" | 
ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password
$credential = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("jrosh.01@yahoo.com", $password)

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

$emailMessage.From = "jrosh.01@yahoo.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "jrosh.01@yahoo.com" )
$emailMessage.subject = "Notificacion de: $($env:computername)"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true

$evento = Get-WinEvent –FilterHashTable @{logname="System"} -MaxEvents 1 | 
Where {$_.ID -Match "1020"}

$emailMessage.Body = @"
    <H1>Alerta Scope DHCP</H1>
    <p>Evento a revisar en: <strong>$($evento.MachineName)</strong>.</p>
    <p>Identificador: <strong>$($evento.Id)</strong>.</p>
    <p>Fecha / Hora: <strong>$($evento.TimeCreated)</strong>.</p>
    <p>Texto: <strong>$($evento.Message)</strong>.</p>
    <br>
    <H5><i>$(get-date)</i></H5>
"@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , 
$emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( 
$emailSmtpUser , $credential );

$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
Write-Host "Correo Enviado..."
```

Comment: Don't know if this is a typo or a bad paste but  `-Patch` should be `-Path` in your `Get-Content` - line 5 Col 25. Also, are you getting an error message when you are trying to send this out?

Comment: ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At C:\Users\USUARIOPC\Pruebas.ps1:6 char:13
+ $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $encrypted
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStr 
   ingCommand

Comment: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "password" is 
null. Change the value of argument "password" to a non-null value."
At C:\Users\USUARIOPC\Pruebas.ps1:7 char:15
+ ... redential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PsCrede ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested mail action not taken: 
mailbox unavailable"
At C:\Users\USUARIOPC\Pruebas.ps1:31 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Comment: You should really post the error messages into your question and format them to make them readable

Comment: From the error message, it looks like your password file does not exist, or isn't being read a.k.a. a null value passed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error messages you submitted it looks like there's a problem with password file. Please make sure that you export your password like this:

```
"P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\Users\USUARIOPC\password2.txt
```

Where `P@ssword1` is your password.

Comment: Thanks for your support.
I already made the request and if I remove two errors.
Only I have left in annexed.

Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested mail action not taken: 
mailbox unavailable"
At C:\Users\USUARIOPC\Pruebas.ps1:28 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
 
Correo Enviado...

Comment: You might want to change to this `$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( 
$emailSmtpUser , $password );` and add `$emailSmtpUser="jrosh.01@yahoo.com"`. In your script you provided username and Credential object which is username and password to `System.Net.NetworkCredential`

Comment: thanks for your support.
Now I only have 1 problem.

---------------------------------------------
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested mail action not taken: 
mailbox unavailable"
At C:\Users\JRSANCHEZ\Pruebas.ps1:38 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException